# How to read all the tags present inside entry tag based on tag name and store its value in a hashmap using java

Tags: java, xml

Here is the xml code in which I want to get value based on tag name which are present under entry tag and store it in hashmap as a key value pair

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title>Isra쭩쳳 doden drie Palestijnse aanvallers</title>
    <updated>2016-02-17T17:13:11.477Z</updated>
    <rights>This material may not be published</rights>
    <content type="text/plain" xml:lang="nl">Isra쭩쳳 doden drie Palestijnse aanvallers</content>
    <apcm:ContentMetadata xmlns:apcm="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/apcm">
        <apcm:Priority Numeric="4" Legacy="r" />
        <apcm:ConsumerReady>TRUE</apcm:ConsumerReady>
        <apcm:ByLine>Paul Gabel</apcm:ByLine>
        <apcm:HeadLine>Isra쭩쳳 doden drie Palestijnse aanvallers</apcm:HeadLine>
        <apcm:OriginalHeadLine>Isra쭩쳳 doden drie Palestijnse aanvallers</apcm:OriginalHeadLine>
        <apcm:Keywords>Westoever</apcm:Keywords>
        <apcm:Cycle>BC</apcm:Cycle>
        <apcm:Selector>-----</apcm:Selector>
        <apcm:SlugLine>Westoever 2016/02/17 22:43:58</apcm:SlugLine>
        <apcm:MediaType>Text</apcm:MediaType>
        <apcm:SubjectClassification System="Editorial" Authority="AP Category Code" Value="DUT" Id="DUT" />
        <apcm:Property Name="EntitlementMatch" Id="urn:publicid:ap.org:product:45147" Value="All Text for Elasticsearch" />
        <apcm:Property Name="SequenceNumber" Value="InSequence" Id="236167493" />
        <apcm:FirstCreated>2016-02-14T15:43:48Z</apcm:FirstCreated>
    </apcm:ContentMetadata>
    <apnm:NewsManagement xmlns:apnm="http://ap.org/schemas/03/2005/apnm">
        <apnm:ManagementId>urn:publicid:ap.org:f02232ade7f4394d95337af4b9200c47</apnm:ManagementId>
        <apnm:ManagementSequenceNumber>0</apnm:ManagementSequenceNumber>
    </apnm:NewsManagement>
</entry>
```

Comment: Please give us the code you have written down

Comment: I wrote code using Document XPathFactory and Node, but i didn't get that

Answer (score 0):

Use JaxB. Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) provides a fast and convenient way to bind XML schemas and Java representations, making it easy for Java developers to incorporate XML data and processing functions in Java applications.

[example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/basic.html)